# Should I have a page file?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, pagefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I keep my swap file on an SSD drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/51724/should-i-keep-my-swap-file-on-an-ssd-drive)

I have 16GB RAM and an SSD (actually two in RAID 0 configuration, but one for argument's sake).

My CPU is very powerful, as is the graphics card. It's a client-side laptop, not a server.

Given this specification, do I really need a page file?

Comment: As always, it depends on what you're doing with your system.  For Minesweeper, no... If you're doing large-scale photo or video editing, probably so.

Comment: @diago This is not a duplicate. That question doesn't ask about the requirement for a swap file. It's all about whther you should keep it on the SSD. My question is whether I need one.

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate quotes a Microsoft article stating you don't need one? Have you actually read the answer?

Comment: I read the question. You should put a link to the answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

With that amount of RAM? I do not see why, no.

If 16GB RAM are not sufficient you are either running a bad piece of software (which would also fill any amount of swap / page-file you throw at it) or a memory hungry piece of software (which you should not run on your laptop :)).