# Virtual Memory and SSDs

Tags: windows-7, ssd, virtual-memory, pagefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual Memory and SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/357357/virtual-memory-and-ssd)

On a Windows 7 system, isn't it more beneficial to leave the page file ON the SSD versus moving it over to a HDD? I've heard some say if you move it off the SSD, the result would be a decrease in speed of the system. Others have said you end up killing sections of the SSD prematurely by keeping it on the SSD.

What's the truth?

Comment: [Should I keep my swap file on an SSD drive?](http://superuser.com/q/51724)

Comment: [Virtual Memory and SSD](http://superuser.com/q/357357)

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is just leave it on SSD.

SSDs' high random data rates make it more comfortable with pagefiles.

and these days SSDs can endurance more data written onto. you have to write TBs of data to use a sector up.